# React Native In-App Purchase Implementation on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap, in-app-purchase-receipt

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a React Native application with a Node.js backend, targeting both Android and iOS platforms. Specifically, I am integrating in-app purchase functionality for auto-renewable subscriptions on the iOS platform. To achieve this, I am utilizing the react-native-iap library, and my implementation is in JavaScript.

I have successfully added subscriptions in the Apple Developer Console, and I am able to fetch them into my app. However, I am encountering an issue during the subscription process on iOS. After clicking on the product in the sandbox UI, a popup with subscription details, including a subscribe button and price, appears. Upon clicking the subscribe button, the system prompts for sign-in, and after entering valid credentials, the transaction does not complete.

Additionally, I am facing challenges in obtaining the purchase receipt. As a newcomer to both React Native and in-app purchases, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to overcome these issues.

Below is the relevant snippet of my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, Alert, Platform } from 'react-native';
import {
  useIAP,
  validateReceiptIos,
  finishTransaction,
  purchaseErrorListener,
  purchaseUpdatedListener,
  clearTransactionIOS,
} from 'react-native-iap';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ITUNES_SHARED_SECRET } from "@env";

const SubscriptionScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const {
    requestSubscription,
    getSubscriptions,
    currentPurchase,
    purchaseHistory,
  } = useIAP();
  const [subscriptionStatus, setSubscriptionStatus] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleGetSubscriptions();
    setupPurchaseListeners(); // Setup purchase listeners on mount
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (purchaseHistory && purchaseHistory.length > 0) {
      const isSubscribed = purchaseHistory.some((purchase) =>
        subscriptionSkus.includes(purchase.productId)
      );

      if (isSubscribed) {
        setSubscriptionStatus(true);
      }
    }
  }, [purchaseHistory]);

  const subscriptionSkus = Platform.select({
# ios: ['subscriptionProductID
'],
  });

  const handleGetSubscriptions = async () => {
    try {
      await getSubscriptions({ skus: subscriptionSkus });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting subscriptions:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleBuySubscription = async (productId) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);

      // Request subscription
      const purchase = await requestSubscription({
        sku: productId,
        ...(Platform.OS === 'ios' && {
          andDangerouslyFinishTransactionAutomaticallyIOS: false,
        }),
      });

      // Note: finishTransaction should be handled within purchaseUpdatedListener

      if (purchase.transactionState === 'Purchased') {
        const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
        await handleValidateReceipt(receipt);
        navigation.navigate('IndexPage');
      } else {
        console.warn('Transaction state:', purchase.transactionState);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.code, err.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleValidateReceipt = async (receipt) => {
    try {
      const isTestEnvironment = false;
      const response = await validateReceiptIos(
        {
          'receipt-data': receipt,
          password: ITUNES_SHARED_SECRET,
        },
        isTestEnvironment
      );

      if (response && response.status === 0) {
        const serverValidationResult = await validateReceiptOnServer(receipt);
        if (serverValidationResult.valid) {
          setSubscriptionStatus(true);
          Alert.alert('Subscription Purchased', 'Thank you for subscribing!');
        } else {
          console.warn('Server validation failed');
        }
      } else {
        console.warn('Receipt validation failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during receipt validation:', error);
    }
  };

  const validateReceiptOnServer = async (receipt) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('YOUR_SERVER_ENDPOINT', { receipt });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error validating receipt on server:', error);
      return { valid: false };
    }
  };

  const setupPurchaseListeners = () => {
    // Listen for purchase errors
    const purchaseErrorSubscription = purchaseErrorListener((error) => {
      console.warn('purchaseErrorListener', error);
    });

    // Listen for purchase updates
    const purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener((purchase) => {
      console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
      if (purchase.transactionState === 'Purchased') {
        const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
        handleValidateReceipt(receipt);
        finishTransaction({ purchase, isConsumable: false });
      }
    });

    return () => {
      // Remove the listeners on unmount
      purchaseErrorSubscription.remove();
      purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkCurrentPurchase = async () => {
      if (currentPurchase) {
        const receipt = currentPurchase.transactionReceipt;
        if (receipt) {
          await handleValidateReceipt(receipt);
          try {
            await finishTransaction({
              purchase: currentPurchase,
              isConsumable: false,
            });
          } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err.code, err.message);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    checkCurrentPurchase();
  }, [currentPurchase, finishTransaction]);

  const handleClearTransactions = async () => {
    try {
      await clearTransactionIOS();
      console.log('Cleared pending transactions.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while clearing transactions:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{subscriptionStatus ? 'Subscribed' : 'Not Subscribed'}</Text>
      {subscriptionSkus.map((sku) => (
        <Button
          key={sku}
          title={`Purchase ${sku}`}
          onPress={() => handleBuySubscription(sku)}
        />
      ))}
      <Button title="Clear Transactions" onPress={handleClearTransactions} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default SubscriptionScreen;
```

I am currently facing challenges with the submission of my application, even after removing payment and subscription functionalities. I have attempted to submit the app without any payment-related features, yet it continues to face rejection.
coz in app purchase business payment apple guidelines

Comment: What "valid credentials" are you using?  You need to use a sandbox user set up in App Store Connect.